# How to search only n levels in a CosmosDB document array?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am building on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441794/how-do-i-get-unique-categories-from-all-documents-in-cosmosdb/53478307?noredirect=1#comment93827169_53478307) question that I asked earlier

The example document is the same

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "locales": [
            {
                "categories": [
                    "Women",
                    "clothing",
                    "tops"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "locales": [
            {
                "categories": [
                    "Men",
                    "test",
                    "tops"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And I am using the following query to get the UNIQUE categories from all documents and this is working fine but I need to further restrict the search so I only get the first 2 levels in the categories array and I cannot figure out how to adjust the query to do that.

From the example document I would only like to get Women, Clothing, Men, Test since those are all in the first 2 levels in the array.

How do I adjust my query to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway,you can't achieve your goal with single sql directly. I still suggest you using the combination of sql and stored procedure.

sql:

```
SELECT l.categories[0] as one, l.categories[1] as two FROM c
join l in c.locales
```

Output:

[image]

Then use above sql in stored procedure to get the results, loop it to filter the duplicate items.

---

Update Answer:

[image]

Duplicate will compare all the elements,so you can't achieve the goal with it directly.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT l.categories[0] as topLevel, l.categories[1] as secondLevel FROM c join l in c.locales, doesn't the DISTINCT keyword resolve this directly?